# css static file in pythonanywhere not found

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere, static-files, web-publishing

I understand that the topic was not raised once, I reread and tried all the options, but for some reason the error does not go away and the styles do not connectenter image description here

[connect static](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGJi9.png)

[path directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpQRA.png)

[error in load site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOzaZ.png)

[path in templates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjuKx.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your own local system static files will be served by the django dev server. In a production setting like PythonAnywhere, you need to set the **STATIC_ROOT** in your `settings.py`, eg: `/home/yourusername/myproject/static`

and then run `python manage.py collectstatic` which will collect static files from your app folders and put them in there

Comment: I did it, but still a mistake - "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"  and path very strange http://yresteria.pythonanywhere.com//static/%09/css/style.css"   what is this '%09' ?

Comment: EEeee!!!! it's work thank you ...i forgot "python manage.py collectstatic"

Answer (score 0):

In your template code remove the **space** from:

```
 (% static    '  css/style.css' %)
               |
               |
               |
               |
             #this one
```

Comment: Sure, #happytohelp